# Find and Highlight Arabic with diacritics Text in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, search, uiwebview, arabic

I'm viewing an Arabic with diacritics (tashkel) text in a UIWebView.
I also have a Search View.

I want to give the UIWebView a keyword and UIWebView finds and highlights it,
but the search should ignore the diacritics.

The main text should remain with the diacritics.

example :
if the text is " الَلَهُم صَلِ عَلى مُحَمّد و آل مُحمد "
and I tell the UIWebView to search for " محمد "
it should highlight "مُحَمّد " and " مُحمد " regardless of all the diacritics.

I think of two approaches :
1- I do the find and highlight by Javascript after the UIWebView load.
2- I edit the text by Objective-C before loading the UIWebView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first strip all the diacritics from the string, then you can compare without any diacritics. Use regular expression to remove the characters you don't want. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdaker/6JeWb/4/) i did, inside the `strip()` function you need to add all the diacritics you need to take out.

hope this helps.

Comment: But I need the main text to be with the diacritics.

Comment: how are you highlighting the text in UIWebView? can you show the code?

Comment: Im thinking of tagging the word i find in a <highlight> tag. Using CSS i will make background color : yellow;

Comment: Well still the only you can search is to strip the diacritics and then compare them. You dont have to change the original text. You strip, search, then reassemble the original text with the highlighted words. I did a [sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/kdaker/FUg85/) that does just that. This simply demonstrates how to think about such a problem. You can expand on that. Hope this helps :)

Comment: btw im curious to know what app are you building?

Comment: cool ! it works. thank you KDaker.
this is my app: [Jenan App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jnan/id545186082?mt=8)
here how it looks like [Search in-Text](http://i.imgur.com/1fzI1.png)

Comment: I faced another problem which is if we search for two words or more.
can you handle this please ? :)

Comment: wells  its quite simple.. youll need to assemble an array of the words you need to highlight.. and then run another embedded for loop to search any of those words.... [here is a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kdaker/FUg85/2/) .. nice app btw :)

Comment: KDaker, could u give me your name please? - i'd like to credit the search for you.

Answer (score 2):

The version below does not remove sukoon.

I have converted the eight diacritics (fatha, kasrah, damma, shaddah, sukoon and tanween) into their Unicode equivalent. It is much easier to manipulate Arabic converted into Latin characters in any text editor :

```html
<html>
 <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<script>document.write("حَرْفٌ".replace(/(\u0652)|(\u0650)|(\u064C)|(\u064E)|(\u064B)|(\u064F)|(\u064D)|(\u0651)/g,""));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Resources used:
[Arabic Keyboard with diacritics](http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/)
[Unicode Code Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/)